# GEE clip image with another image generates new shape

Tags: python, google-earth-engine, clip, geemap

**Edit: I have changed the clip to updateMask function. when I print the image dimensions it seems to be ok with size, but when I export image GCS and then open again, it adds empty row /column to the image. I couldn't find any reason why.**

I have two images which are different size . I want to clip img2 using img 1, and to get image that has the exactly same dimensions as img1.

img1 has the following shape: [425, 327]
img2 has the following shape: [426, 329]

I have tried to clip them using GEE as following:

```
img1=ee.Image.loadGeoTIFF(url_one)
img2=ee.Image.loadGeoTIFF(url_two)



clipped=img2.UpdateMask(img1.select('B1'))

#print of imgs size
sz_clip=clipped.getInfo()['bands'][0]['dimensions']
sz_img2=img2.getInfo()['bands'][0]['dimensions']
sz_orig=img1.getInfo()['bands'][0]['dimensions']

print(f'img1 size:{sz_orig}  img2 size"{sz_be}    clipped size: {sz_clip}')

>>>
original size:[425, 327]  img2 size"[426, 329]    clipped size: [426, 328]
```

My problem is that I need to get the clipped img with the same size as img1, but this doesn't happen and I get something new.

I though maybe it has to do with projection, so I have tried to do the same but to reproject img2 to have the same projection as img 1 before clipping:

```
projection_img1=sen.projection()

img2_reproj=img2.reproject(crs=projection_img1)

#tried also like this but same size result:
img2_reproj=img2.reduceResolution(reducer=ee.Reducer.mean()).reproject(crs=projection_img1)

...

original size:[425, 327]  img2 size"[426, 329]    clipped size: [426, 328]
```

I still don't have clipped_size with the same size as img1.

**My end goal is to have the clipped image with the exactly same shape as img1.**

Answer (score 0):

Are the two images registered / georeferenced? Do they overlap the way you'd expect when imported? Can you share the assets that were imported?